# вывод данных из Excel в двумерный массив c++

Tags: c++, excel

Нужно простой код на с++ Visual studio для считывания данных из ячеек и записи их в двумерный массив.

Comment: Нужно кросс платформенное решение или только windows? Можно ли требовать чтобы на машине конечного пользователя был установлен Excel?

Comment: Кросс, и excel установлен